# Pandas: display groupby aggregate statistic with data

Tags: python, pandas

[Data Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIQY1.png)

I am trying to add a new column to my data frame that displays the average purchase amount per user. The data frame is called trainDf and the below line of code produces the average by user. I'm trying to learn how to add it as a column to display similar  to the above image.

```py
AveragePurchaseAmountUser = trainDf.groupby(by='User_ID')['Purchase_Amount'].mean()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
trainDf['AveragePurchaseAmountUser'] = trainDf.groupby(['User_ID'])['Purchase_Amount'].mean()
```

Comment: This will fill the 'AveragePurchaseAmountUser' column with NaNs, as pandas won't by default match the series to the dataframe column values.

Comment: Confirmed. Fills column with NaNs

Answer (score 0):

I would use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
avg_df = trainDf.groupby(by='User_ID')['Purchase_Amount'].mean().reset_index().rename(columns={'Purchase_Amount': 'Avg'})
trainDf = trainDf.merge(avg_df, on='User_ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the DataFrame with the new column

```
def avg(df):
    df['Average_Purchase_Amount'] = df['Purchase_Amount'].mean()
    return df

newDf = trainDf.groupby(by='User_ID').apply(avg)
```

And if you want the column as a Series you can apply this function:

```
def avgSeries(df):
    return pd.Series(data = df['Purchase_Amount'].mean(), index = df.index)
```

Then add the column to you DataFrame later

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`transform`](http://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html) is for

```
AveragePurchaseAmountUser = trainDf.groupby(by='User_ID')['Purchase_Amount'].transform() .mean()
```

I can't test atm, but you might need

```
...transform('mean')
```

Instead

Comment: When I run this line it produces the following error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'mean'

Comment: I forgot parentheses